# Is there a way to make this code faster?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have a C++ struct that I need to convert to a list so that I can load into GPU

```
struct point_cloud_tensor
{
    std::vector<float>               timestamp;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>  position;
    // more fields
};


point_cloud_tensor sweep_to_array(const point_sweep &point_sweep)
{
    const auto         num_points = point_sweep.points.size();
    point_cloud_tensor tensor;

    point_cloud_tensor.timestamp.reserve(num_points);
    point_cloud_tensor.point.reserve(num_points);

    for (int i = 0; i < point_sweep.points.size(); i++)
    {
        const auto point = point_sweep.points.at(i);
        tensor.timestamp.push_back(point.timestamp);

        std::vector<double> point_triple(3);
        point_triple.push_back(point.x);
        point_triple.push_back(point.y);
        point_triple.push_back(point.z);
        tensor.position.push_back(point_triple);
        // more fields
    }

    return tensor;
}
```

There are about 100K points in the sweep vector and this runs in about 30ms.

Is there a way to substantially reduce this?

Comment: Don't use std::vector for small fixed size arays like 3-coordinates, ever.

Comment: What should I use instead? Could you provide an answer?

Comment: @samol `std::array` or `std::tuple` depending on usage

Comment: Do you really want to create `point_triple` as a vector of six values, 0.0 repeated three times, then, the x, y and z values? That seems...strange.

Comment: Looping over `i` known to fall in the range `[0, point_sweep.points.size())` and then using `.at(i)` instead of `[i]` is kinda pointless; `.at(i)` gets you bounds checking on something that you've guaranteed won't run out of  bounds. Why not just `for (const auto& point : point_sweep.points) {` for both simplicity and a small amount of speed up?

Comment: Use std::array, std::tuple, a struct with 3 members, a struct with a C-style array of 3 coordinates inside, or just store coordinates in a flat 3*N-sized vector in the first place. I cannot post an anawer because I don't havebyour hardware and cannot verify any speed improvement, but you should be able to answer your own question after measuring it.

Comment: Vectors of vectors are not awesome either. That's a lot of indirection that'll ruin your cache locality

Comment: Also make sure you are compiling with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Use a profiler to see where the hot spots are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Do not call size() every time if it does not change

Since you already store `point_sweep.points.size()` into the variable `num_points`, you can use it in your `for` loop. When you iterate like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < point_sweep.points.size(); i++)
```

Every iteration you will dereference `point_sweep` and dereference `points` to call its method `size()`. It should be faster to use the local variable instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
```

#### Use a reference when appropriate

When you fetch your point:

```
const auto point = point_sweep.points.at(i);
```

You are calling the copy constructor for no reason. You should use a reference to it, using `&`:

```
const auto& point = point_sweep.points.at(i);
```

References can be risky because every modification you perform will be applied to the original object, but since you are using a `const reference`, you should be safe.

#### Minimize the calls when pushing elements to the back of a vector

When you fill up your `tensor.position` vector, you may:

1. Create the point with an [intializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)
2. Add the item without a temporary variable, in order to be move-able

So, this code:

```
std::vector<double> point_triple(3);
point_triple.push_back(point.x);
point_triple.push_back(point.y);
point_triple.push_back(point.z);
tensor.position.push_back(point_triple);
```

Becomes:

```
tensor.position.push_back({point.x, point.y, point.z});
```

Plus it becomes easier to read, in my opinion.

#### Use another 3D point structure (if possible)

Also, as others have pointed out, if you can change the data structures then you may use an [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or you may simply write a struct such as `struct Point { double x, y, z; }`. The array can be accessed almost exactly like a vector, which should make the transition a bit easier. The tuple must be accessed by std::get which needs to rewrite a bit of code. For example if you want to display the contents of the last element:

```
struct point_cloud_tensor
{
    std::vector<float>                            timestamp;
    std::vector<std::tuple<double,double,double>> position;
    // more fields
} tensor;
auto last_pos = tensor.position.back();
std::cout << "x=" << std::get<0>(last_pos) << ' ';
std::cout << "y=" << std::get<1>(last_pos) << ' ';
std::cout << "z=" << std::get<2>(last_pos) << std::endl;
```

However, with tuples you can add items with [emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), which saves you a move constructor, e.g.:

```
tensor.position.emplace_back(point.x, point.y, point.z);
```

Notice the difference in syntax. With push_back you have one parameter `{point.x, point.y, point.z}` but with emplace_back you have 3 parameters `point.x, point.y, point.z`. Basically with emplace_back you are just removing the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your `std::vector` is being used for a small sized array, for this you can replace it by `std:array` 
As mentioned, testing how fast a code can be run, is a matter of hardware so I can't be 100% sure if it is faster with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about making step backward and creating a list when constructing points?